# VBA Compare items in column and count duplicates

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to write a macro that will count duplicate values in a column. They have already been sorted into ascending order, so I'm trying to use a modification on a bubble sort that compares values in column C, and if it's the same as the one before increase the count and print it into column H. When I try to run the code it's telling me my "If" statement is out of range. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? VBA syntax is pretty new to me. Thanks for your help!

```
Dim colArray() As Variant
colArray() = Range(Range("C6"), Range("C6").End(xlDown)).Value

Dim a As Long, b As Long
Dim temp As Variant
For a = LBound(colArray) To UBound(colArray) - 1
    For b = a + 1 To UBound(colArray)
        If colArray(a) = colArray(b) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        
        Else
            counter = 1
    
        End If

        temp = colArray(b)
        colArray(b) = colArray(a)
        colArray(a) = temp
        Set countStart = Range("H6")
        countStart.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = counter

    Next b
Next a
```

Comment: `colArray` is a 2D array.

Comment: In the line `countStart.Offset(i - 1...` you're using a variable i that isn't declared and doesn't have a value set. (Not part of the if statement, but an issue nonetheless.)

Comment: Start by replacing any instance of `colArray(a)` or `colArray(b)` with `colArray(a, 1)` and `colArray(b, 1)`, respectively.

Comment: And remove the brackets from the Dim statement

Comment: @ Peter, it's declared elsewhere earlier in the code. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

If you have sorted column C into ascending order so that identical values will be consecutive then entering this simple formula into column H cell H2 and drag it down will do what you want (no VBA macro needed):

```
 =IF(C2=C1, H1+1,0)  '' 0 = no repeats etc...
```

I chose to count the number of repeats of the previous line. I prefer to avoid macros unless they are absolutely essential to the function of a spreadsheet. Many corporates don't like them. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for this, but my boss wants to automate our process so it has to be in a macro. I'll see if I can use that somehow though to translate.